# ALSA snd_aloop appears as 'internal audio'

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm using ALSA module snd_aloop in order to be able to broadcast output from my ALSA DJ software to the net (ie facebook live, Zoom)
I load it via modprobe. It works quite well. I can switch between this loopback and my internal microphone and it works great.

BUT I have an annoying issue : Both my hardware soundcard and the virtual loopback one appear as 'Internal audio Stereo Analogue' ('Audio interne Stéréo Analogique on my french system).

They share this same name in ubuntu sounds prefs, in pavucontrol, and in the apps/browser audio selector.

I would like to call snd_aloop source and sink differently, ie 'Loopback', so I could distinguish them other than by trial-error each time.

I studied very interesting detailed docs about Alsa and Pulse, did some 'pacmd update-source-proplist', but could not manage to change the name if snd_aloop.

Could anyone be able to help me ?

Thank a lot

For clarification, here is my list-sinks output :
I would like the last
device.description = "Audio interne Stéréo analogique"
to show something different

```
jmj@jmj-yoga2:~$ pacmd list-sinks | grep -e name -e description
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-surround71>
        alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xb0518000 irq 16"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.name = "Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-surround71"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI)"
        device.description = "Audio interne Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel Haswell HDMI"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
        alsa.name = "ALC3239 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xb051c000 irq 22"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.name = "8 Series HD Audio Controller"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Stéréo analogique"
        device.description = "Audio interne Stéréo analogique"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC3239"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    name: <alsa_output.platform-snd_aloop.0.analog-stereo>
        alsa.name = "Loopback PCM"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.card_name = "Loopback"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Loopback 1"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_aloop"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Stéréo analogique"
        device.description = "Audio interne Stéréo analogique"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Loopback Mixer"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

regards